# Extract Multiple Key Value Pairs from a Line

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a document to build searchable data. The document has multiple key/value pairs that are determined by a colon `:`. Some lines have multiple key/value pairs on the same line. The tricky part is that aside from a colon, the strings for both the key name and the value are inconsistent. For example, there may be 1 space or 4 spaces between the colon and the value, each value can have spaces in it, and there can be an indeterminate number of spaces between the key/value pairs that are within the same line.

Example document:

```
   Name:   John Smith
   Address: 123 Main St, Some City, ST 12345       Country:  US
   Date 1: 1/2/17 Date 2: 1/2/18
```

I need to extract:

```
    {
      "Name"    : "John Smith",
      "Address" : "123 Main St, Some City, ST 12345",
      "Country" : "US",
      "Date 1"  : "1/2/17",
      "Date 2"  : "1/2/18"
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can have any number of spaces in keys, values and in between, there is no way to tell when a value ends and the next key begins. Take the last line of your example document, for example: Is it `"Date 1":"1/2/17", "Date 2":"1/2/18"` or rather `"Date 1": "1/2/17 Date", "2": "1/2/18"`. So, without any further assumptions, you cannot clearly separate serveral key/value pairs on a line.

If you only have a fixed set of possible keys, just add these as tokens and look for occurrences of a key token, followed by a ":".

If this fails, you could make some more assumptions about the format of your keys and values. For example, you could assume that a key always starts with an alphabetic character. *Warning*: Such ad-hoc assumptions often overlook fringe cases and may lead to unclean data.

Comment: I think I am going to have to go with the assumptions and fixed keys approach (which I was trying to avoid), but even this is becoming quite messy. I would ask for the document to be reformatted, however, there are years and years of these that will need to be processed, so it is not feasible to manually do such a thing. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Hugging face transformer's question-answering model. (XLM Roberta for example)